# Updating redux form fields with value after fetch request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

So i'm doing an address finder component in react and i want to know the best way to update the fields with values after i pull the data back from the API. So at the moment i am using a fetch in react to retrieve data and populate some form fields then setting their value as different states when the API is returned.

Now if you use normal  etc etc this works. If you change this to use redux's form field

Code example is below:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Field } from 'redux-form';

class AddressFinder extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      data: {},
      postCode: ''
    };
    this.searchPostCode = this.searchPostCode.bind(this);
  }

  searchPostCode(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let Input = document.getElementsByClassName('postCodeSearch');
    let postCode = Input[0].value;

    const url = 'http://getaddressfinderurl/' + postCode + '';
    fetch(url)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({ 
          data: res,
        });
        return res
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log('Error happened during fetching!', err);
      });

    this.setState({ 
      data: res,
    });

  }

  updateBox(premisesName) {
    this.setState({ 
      premise: premisesName,
      data: []
    });
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.data);
    return (
      <div className='address-finder'>
        <label className="app-form__field-label">{this.props.field.Label}</label>
        <input
          type='text'
          className='postCodeSearch app-form__input field'
          name='postCodeSearch'
        />
        <button onClick={this.searchPostCode}>Find Address</button>
        {this.state.data.premisesNames ?
          <ul className='address-finder__list'>
            {this.state.data.premisesNames.map((item, index) => <li onClick={() => this.updateBox(item.premisesName)} key={index} value={item.premisesName}>{item.premisesName}</li>)}
          </ul>
          : null
        }
        <Field
          type='text'
          className='app-form__input field cF'
          name='premise'
          value={this.state.data.premise}
          component='input'
        />
        <Field
          type='text'
          className='app-form__input field cF'
          name='streetName'
          component='input'
          value={this.state.data.streetName}
        />
        <Field
          type='text'
          className='app-form__input field cF'
          name='town'
          component='input'
          value={this.state.data.town}
        />
        <Field
          type='text'
          className='app-form__input field cF'
          name='postCode'
          component='input'
          value={this.state.data.postCode}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default AddressFinder;
```

Comment: `Now if you use normal etc etc this works. If you change this to use redux's form field`. Looks like some parts of your question are missing?

Answer (score 0):

`value` is not a prop you can pass to the `Field` it is just an instance prop. In your code you are not even using Redux afaik.

In `redux-form` values are set at the form level not at each field level.

To achieve this you can setup your `form` to pick the value from redux, and instead of using `setState` in your component you dispatch a redux action. At the end of the action the redux state will update and this update will trigger an update to your form values. The flow is documented in https://redux-form.com/7.4.2/examples/initializefromstate/